# Not found string value on array

Tags: java, netbeans-8

I am a beginner on java.

Why it always show not found?

and how exactly make a not found string value on array?

```
    String[] array = new String[10];
    String b = "5";
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        String in = String.valueOf(i);
        array[i] = in;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        if (b.equals(array[i])) {
            System.out.println("found " + array[i]);
        } else if (!b.equals(array[i])) {
            System.out.println("not found");
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Right now, you abort the _whole program_ as soon as you find anything that _doesn't_ match `b`.  The first element doesn't match, so it aborts immediately rather than continuing to search.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  It looks like you need to learn to use a debugger.  Please help yourself to some [complementary debugging techniques](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  If you still have issues afterwards, please feel free to come back with a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: @JoeC So why is this not an MCVE?  This is a better example than many I've seen here lately, between those who expect us to mind-read their program and those who throw 300 lines of code at us and say "It doesn't work".  This question provided just around the right amount of info.

Comment: Tip: The answer shows that you don't need the `else` in this case.  But when you do need it, you don't need to repeat the condition with a `!`.  Once the program gets to the else, we already _know_ that `b.equals(array[i])` is false, so you don't need to add another `if` to test for it.  Just saying `} else {` would be enough.  (And there are some cases where adding the extra `if` would make your program not compile.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your second `for` loop terminates on `i = 0` when you call `System.exit(0);` (the program actually terminates overall when you call that).

```
} else if (!b.equals(array[i])) {
    System.out.println("not found");
    System.exit(0);
}
```

Suggest changing the logic to *break from the loop* when the match has been found.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  if (b.equals(array[i])) {
     System.out.println("found " + array[i]);
     break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay i've been figure it out.

Thanks for the advice.

Just make "not found" statement outside the loop.

```
String[] array = new String[10];
    String b = "10";
    boolean c = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        String in = String.valueOf(i);
        array[i] = in;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        if (b.equals(array[i])) {
            System.out.println("found " + array[i]);
        } else if (!b.equals(array[i])) {
            c = true;
            }
    }
    if (c == true){
        System.out.println("not found");
    }
}
```